# JQuery mobile constantly displays ajax spinner

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My `JQuery mobile` page constantly displays the ajax spinner like this:

[image]

This is the HTML code with all the references to `jquery`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="static/jquery.js"></script>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

How do i remove it?

Comment: can you check the contents of static/jquery.js and static/jquery.mobile.js

Comment: It looks like you are referencing all the scripts and css twice each.  Try one link to the CSS, then one script tag for jquery followed by one script tag for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Your link to the jQuery mobile stylesheet has a space.

Comment: @ezanker if i remove the link to the CSS or link to jquery, the page doesn't render as a jquery mobile page.

Comment: @Anurag What would i be looking for? I tried to search for "jquery" or "spinner" in jquery.mobile.js, i don't find anything.

Comment: @JamieDunstan that only appears in the question.In my original code, it's not so.Thanks though.

Comment: Don't remove the link, just make sure each link is only there once instead of twice.

Comment: Yeah, saw what you meant after i posted that comment.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean.

You need hide ultil page complete load.
Try this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#loading').hide();
});
```

Comment: No, my friend, this doesn't help.